# Copy Azure CloudPageBlob to CloudBlockBlob

Tags: c#, blob, storage, azcopy

Have a load of Azure page blobs in an Azure storage account which need copying to block blobs so they can be set from "cold" to "Archive" storage tier.  The page blobs are created by SQL server (pre 2016) BACKUP TO URL.

I spoke to Microsoft about this and they suggested AzCopy with Azure File blob as a stepping stone, e.g.  Page blob -> block blob (file storage) -> block blob (Blob storage).  This all works fine in AzCopy or GUI based Azure tools but I need to automate it and build in some resilience.

Problem I have is I cannot get a Cloud**Page**Blob to copy to Cloud**Block**Blob
not matter how I cast it.  This is a cut-down example to show (lack of) progress and how I'm going about this.  I will wrap this in a Task<> in production but I cannot get the .StartCopy to work.  Any ideas?

```
    CredentialEntity ce = Utils.GetBlobCredentials();
    StorageCredentials sc = new StorageCredentials(ce.Name, ce.Key);

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(ce.Name, ce.Key), true);

    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(@"archive");
    CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(@"xfer");

    CloudPageBlob source = sourceContainer.GetPageBlobReference("test.bak");
    CloudBlockBlob target = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("new.bak");

    //target.StartCopy(source);

    //target.StartCopyAsync()
```

Comment: Azure Files are not "blobs" there is no concept of "block" and "page" azure filesDataMovement library copy performs an asynchronous copy (meaning expects service to pull data from source) that cannot "cast" the blob

Comment: AzCopy has an option to download the blob, so I wonder how I can replicate this (lack of downloading) in C#.  Do I download to a stream then copy back to an Azure file?  Some of these blobs are almost 1TB in size.

Comment: Have you referred to the samples script https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/tree/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples